# Infinitesimal parametric Lorentz transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames

Let $\Lambda$ be an element of the Lorentz group and $\eta$ the flat metric. I need to show that the condition $$\Lambda_\rho^\mu\Lambda_\sigma^\nu\eta_\sigma^\rho=\eta^{\mu\nu}$$ for an infinitesimal $\Lambda_\beta^\alpha=\delta_\beta^\alpha+\omega_\beta^\alpha$ implies that $\omega$ is antisymmetric.

So here's what I have done so far: $$\Lambda_\rho^\mu\Lambda_\sigma^\nu\eta_\sigma^\rho=(\delta_\rho^\mu+\omega_\rho^\mu)(\delta_\sigma^\nu+\omega_\sigma^\nu)\eta^{\rho\sigma}=\eta^{\mu\nu}+\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\mu\sigma}+\omega_\rho^\mu\eta^{\rho\nu}+\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\rho\sigma}=\eta^{\mu\nu}$$ which means we must have $\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\mu\sigma}+\omega_\rho^\mu\eta^{\rho\nu}+\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\rho\sigma}=0$. How do I continue?

Edit. Obviously by moving the indexes up and down: $$\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\mu\sigma}+\omega_\rho^\mu\eta^{\rho\nu}+\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\sigma^\nu\eta^{\rho\sigma}=\omega^{\nu\mu}+\omega^{\mu\nu}+\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\nu^\rho=0.$$ But why is $\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\nu^\rho=0$?

Comment: And so, what is the condition for $\omega$ to be antisymmetric?

Comment: I guess, $\omega^{\mu\nu}+\omega^{\nu\mu}=0$.

Comment: Although for that to happen we must have $\omega_\rho^\mu\omega_\nu^\rho=0$, right? But why is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quadratic term vanishes simply because we're working to first order. In other words, if $\Lambda^\alpha{}_\beta = \delta^\alpha{}_\beta + \omega^\alpha{}_\beta$ exactly, with no infinitesimals, then $\omega$ is not antisymmetric. But if we interpret it as a first order expansion, then the first order term is antisymmetric.